# Update Datepicker element value in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to parse historical data from https://www.investing.com. I need my output in a CSV. Below is the code that I am using:

```
#driver configurations
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, 
desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities(), 
executable_path='C:\\Users\\akiedi7\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://www.investing.com/{}/{}-historical-data'

type = 'indices'
index = 'eu-stoxx50'


new_link = url.format(type,index)
driver.get(new_link)

picker = driver.find_element_by_class_name('float_lang_base_1')
sdate = picker.find_element_by_tag_name('input').get_attribute('value')
sdate.clear()
```

I am able to extract the date value as a String but how do I update the value of the date range and extract data?

Also, how will I be able to download the data in the choice of my location?

Comment: `picker = driver.find_element_by_class_name('float_lang_base_1')` finds the first element matching that class, and that element is the "Euro Stoxx 50 (STOXX50E)" header. Are you sure you are looking at the right "picker"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript.

```
document.getElementById("picker").setAttribute("value","new_value")

query = 'document.getElementById("picker").setAttribute("value","new_value")'
driver.execute_script(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your `new_link`:

```
picker=driver.find_element_by_id('datePickerIconWrap')
date = picker.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='hasDatepicker']")
# you are dealing with an input field with  type=hidden, so click it like this
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", date)  

#Update Start Date; I've used some example dates
start_date=driver.find_element_by_id('startDate')
start_date.clear()
start_date.send_keys("01/02/2020")

#Update End Date
end_date=driver.find_element_by_id('endDate')
end_date.clear()
end_date.send_keys("12/02/2020")

#Click Apply
driver.find_element_by_id('applyBtn').click()
```

**Note:** You need this import in case you don't have it already, to send keys:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I have read that it's not advisable to use xpath since the HTML structure of the website might change frequently. Is that the case? If yes, what would be a fullproof alternative?

Comment: Wherever possible, it's best to use IDs as they should be unique. Your website could obviously still change these.
Having said that, xpath is a very robust and at the same time flexible way of identifying elements.
I have updated the answer to use picker id. 'date' still needs to be identified differently as the element does not have an html id.

Comment: perfect! Cheers :)